# Parameter Issues in Update Procedure Gridview ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, stored-procedures

My Error:

***Procedure or function `UpdateListDetails` has too many arguments specified.***

My problem is as follows: 
I need my gridview to be editable ONLY at the `Qty` field. My stored procedure needs both the edited row's `IC_No` and a label `lblDisp_ListNo` as parameters. I have turned on the `AutoGenerateEditButton`

My GridView's Bound fields

`--------------------
IC_No | Name | Qty |
--------------------`

My SQL source details:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sourceListDetails" 
runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" 
UpdateCommand="UpdateListDetails" 
UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">

<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="NewQty" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="old_IC_No" Type="String" />
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="old_List_No" Type="String" ControlID="lblDisp_ListNo" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

This is my update procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateListDetails]
@NewQty         int,
@old_List_No varchar(15),
@old_IC_No  varchar(15)
AS
BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE IP_List_Details 
SET Qty_Requested = @NewQty 
WHERE List_No=@old_List_No
    AND IC_No=@old_IC_No
END
GO
```

Comment: you have error in procedue or in gridview?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad The procedure works fine when I feed parameters to it directly.

Comment: you should call procedure form code behind and bind with GridView